# Routing transition between 2 components without destroying first one?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

After searching for a whole day I'am stuck so I would like to ask for some help.

How can I achieve something like this in angular2:
http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/#/page/1

What I mean is how to seamlessly transition between 2 pages using Router ?
I can animate page change, but it's like this right now:

animation-in->first page loaded->animation-out->**empty router outlet(as component is destroyed)**->animation-in->second page loaded

But I would like to have:

animation-in->first page loaded->animation-out of first page->animation-in of second page->second page loaded->and here destroy first page

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I don't think there is an easy solution currently but the Angular team is working on animation support AFAIK.

Comment: hmm yeah i thought so, but any pointers to hard solution ? :) what in angular is responsible for removing / adding component to router outlet ? can i for example extend router-outlet  to delay removing of "prev" route component ?

Comment: Hmm, not that I look at the source. All you need is happening in the the [RouterOutlet](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/router/directives/router_outlet.ts). It is common to use a custom implementation for authorization. I think it shouldn't be too hard to create a custom implementation for your purposes as well. For an example see http://www.captaincodeman.com/2016/03/31/angular2-route-security/

Answer (score 3):

ok, so i got it working, if anyone is interested, here's my solution - any pointers to better one are welcome as i'am noob in angular world :)

```
public activate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction): Promise<any> {
      let previousInstruction = this.currentInstruction;

      this.currentInstruction = nextInstruction;

      let componentType = nextInstruction.componentType;
      let childRouter = this.parentRouter.childRouter(componentType);

      let providers = ReflectiveInjector.resolve([
          provide(RouteData, {useValue: nextInstruction.routeData}),
          provide(RouteParams, {useValue: new RouteParams(nextInstruction.params)}),
          provide(routerMod.Router, {useValue: childRouter})
      ]);

      this.previousComponentRef = this.currentComponentRef;

      return this.loader.loadNextToLocation(componentType, this.currentElementRef, providers)
          .then((componentRef) => {

              this.currentComponentRef = componentRef;

              Observable.of(true).delay(100).toPromise().then(response => {
                if(this.previousComponentRef){
                  this.previousComponentRef.location.nativeElement.className = 'animateout';
                }
                this.currentComponentRef.location.nativeElement.className = 'animatein';
              });

              if (hasLifecycleHook(hookMod.routerOnActivate, componentType)) {
                  return (<OnActivate>componentRef.instance)
                      .routerOnActivate(nextInstruction, previousInstruction);
              }
          });


}


public routerCanDeactivate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction): Promise<boolean> {
    if (isBlank(this.currentInstruction)) {
        return this.resolveToTrue;
    }

    let ref = this.currentComponentRef;

    Observable.of(true).delay(2000).toPromise().then(response => {
        ref.destory();
    });

    return this.resolveToTrue;
}
```

as you can see a i have extended router-outlet and implemented two above methods where first adds animation classes to component, and second one waits with components dispose to allow animation, here's example animation (dm-page,dm-home,dm-contact are component selectors):

```
dm-page, dm-home, dm-contact{position: fixed;top:100%; left:0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: top .8s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: top .8s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: top .8s ease-in-out;
transition: top .8s ease-in-out;}

.animatein {top:0;}
.animateout {top:-100%;}
```

Comment: **update**

`.dispose()` is `destroy()` **since beta.16**

Comment: hi, i have updated .dispose to .destroy and Incjector to ReflectiveInjector as i updated today to beta.17.
i have another question - when i have nested animation-outlet it animates parent and child component even when navigating only child routes.
is there any way to not initialize root animation-outlet when navigating child routes ?

Comment: Could you update this code to RC4? Like use the new router api and new dynamic loading api?

Comment: i think it's better to wait for rc5 or even later, from what i've been reading angular2 animations will do it a lot better than my simple solution

Comment: update on Angular 5 (Beta): deprecated ReflectiveInjector and introduced StaticInjector.